# sh command not found on Windows 10

Tags: command-line, windows-10, sh

I'm trying to install [devkit](http://docs.gameclosure.com/guide/install.html) using the command `npm install -g devkit`. It makes a loading bar which goes on for a few minutes then gives an error, firstly saying that the `sh` command can't be found, then some stuff about how I should tell the creators of devkit about it. When I type sh into cmd myself it's still not found, how can I make it so I can use it?

Comment: Did you follow these instructions to install devkit?...https://github.com/gameclosure/devkit/wiki/Install-Instructions---Windows

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have, I'm just re-installing some of them to make sure though.

Comment: "Note the location that each of the above dependencies is installed to because they will need to be added to your Windows environment PATH." Did you do this?

Comment: it still says that sh isn't found

Comment: I have all of them installed, the problem is that I need the sh command and I don't have it, how can I get it